# VS 13/15 diagnostics vs DotTrace

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, dottrace, diagnostic-tools

Hey whats the difference between those two ?

I currently tried to Google that but with no progress.

Is DotTrace better than built-in diagnostic ?

If yes so for what we are paying?

Comment: Talk to JetBrains's presale or perform your own evaluation. Just not a question that meets Stack Overflow standard.

Comment: I am using DotTrace because I found no way to enable Diagnostic Tools in VS 2015 Enterprise SP 3. I had the same error, which you can find all over the internet, but I found no solution. DotTrace does excactly what it promises and it only runs, if you want to. After stopping your debugging session, all performance results are kept until you decide to delete them. I can not make a comparison, but I can say, that DotTrace did exactly what I expected and in a very self explaining fashion, where I didn't need any manual or guidance at all. Give it try.